# Как удалить из arResult удалённые и неактивные товары ? Битрикс

Tags: php, массивы, битрикс, mvc

В стандартном компоненте корзины Битрикс `(bitrix:sale.basket.basket)`, есть функционал вывода удалённых и неактивных товаров. То есть человек кладёт в корзину товар, Администратор удаляет товар из инфоблока, но у пользователя он остаётся в корзине с пометкой "Недоступен". В `$arResult` у этого товара появляется ключ `"NOT_AVIABLE" => "true"`. Все бы хорошо но при такой ситуация пользователь не может оформить заказ из-за этого товара. Появляется ошибка. В общем создаются проблемы с работой магазина.

Вопрос в том как полностью удалить из `$arResult` такие товары. Чтобы они и не попадали в корзину. Признак таких товаров - ключ `NOT_AVIABLE`.

Я пробывал делать в файле `result_modifier.php` шаблона так.

```
foreach($arResult["GRID"]["ROWS"] as $key => $arItem)
{
     if(isset($arItem['NOT_AVAILABLE'])){
           unset($arResult["GRID"]["ROWS"][$key]);
     }
}
```

Это не помогло. Во-первых ключ удаляется не полностью !? в массиве все равно остаётся ключ с id товара и несколькими вложенными ключами.

Да и впринципе я просто удаляю ключ из массива который уже в представление. Хотелось бы его удалять сразу в контроллере, так чтобы получать уже правильный массив?

Comment: если не путаю, то в `$arResult` еще где-то лежит этот массив товаров и если у вас шаблон стандартный, то js обработка вроде как берет его из другого места, могу ошибаться, но на скорую руку мне это припоминается, попробуйте дамп `$arResult` посмотреть

Comment: @maxkrasnov да эти удалённые товары попадают в $arResult , если его его сдампить то они там есть ) я же все описал в вопросе. Вопрос в том как их удалить из $arResult полностью, и на уровне контроллера. А не во вьюхе удалять уже готовый массив, так в корзине их не будет , а в заказе они остаются

Comment: я имел ввиду, что массив `$arResult["GRID"]["ROWS"]` не единственный, где список товаров в этом массиве `$arResult` хранится, но могу путать с другим компонентом

Comment: Настройка-Настройка модулей-Торговый каталог. В блоке "Значения параметров товаров по умолчанию" на вкладке "Настройки": 1. Включить количественный учет – Да; 2. азрешить покупку при отсутствии товара (включая разрешение отрицательного количества товара) – Нет.
В настройках компонента каталога "Недоступные товары" и "Недоступные торговые предложения" - "не отображать".

Comment: @NikolajSarry я это уже сделал, все настройки так стоят, но всё равно попадают в корзину удалённые товары

Comment: Создайте событие на удаление товара из инфоблока, которое удаляет все привязанный товары из корзин пользователей

Comment: @Oleksandr да так и решили , через задачи битрикса

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы при удалении товара, по событию не посмотреть есть ли он в корзинах у пользователей и просто удалить из корзины.

Для скорости это можно сделать даже прямым запросом к БД. Так же по событию, разумеется)